# How to change spacing system based on screen width Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am having a component like this

```
<Box px={3}>
  <Content />
</Box>
```

Actually when this code is rendered in mobile, there is no problem. But the paddingX still keep equal to 24px (I use 8 base - 8*3=24) when my app is rendered on desktop or bigger screen.

P/s : I tried to modify theme.spacing in theme.js but it seems to be Material UI don't allow us customize spacing based on breakpoints.

So my question is, how can I change spacing system based on screen width?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the mediaQuery hooks that may help you fetch the width i.e. lg, md, sm
 and based on that you can conditionally modify the spacing.

Source: [Link to the documentation with example](https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/#usemediaquery-hook)

Comment: Notice that spacing will only take effect **after** all CSS and JS been loaded and parsed. Prefer CSS solution to avoid [Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS)](https://web.dev/cls/)

Answer (score 25):

You cannot change the spacing base value on each breakpoint but you can change the spacing multiplier on each breakpoint:

```
<Box px={{xs:1, sm:2, md:3}}>
  <Content />
</Box>
```

Support both margin and padding props

Customize breakpoint value can be done by implement `createMuiTheme`:

https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/#custom-breakpoints

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
const theme = createMuiTheme(
   {breakpoints: {
    values: {
      xs: 0,
      sm: 600,
      md: 900,
      lg: 1200,
      xl: 1600,
    },
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is [yet to be implemented](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15631).

A workaround as suggested by [rnanania](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/16383#issuecomment-570074713) is to conditionally set spacing based on breakpoint detection:

```js
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/styles';

const theme = useTheme();
const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('xs'), {
  defaultMatches: true
});

<Grid container spacing={isMobile ? 0 : 4}>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

so I was trying to get this functionality with the MUI theme. I wanted that theme.spacing will return a different number based on media query. here is my solution. **it's not the best because it does not reacts to media query changes after the first render but that works for me.**

override the theme.spacing methode to get this functionality :

```
const originalSpacing = theme.spacing;

function extractMediaQuery(fullMediaString /* shape of : '@media (min-    width:960px)' */) {
  const cutFromIndex = fullMediaString.indexOf('(');
  /* shape of : '(min-width:960px)' */
  return fullMediaString.substring(cutFromIndex);
}

const mediaQueriesStrings = {
  upMd: extractMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up('md')),
  smDown: extractMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm')),
};

theme.spacing = (...args) => {
  if (window.matchMedia(mediaQueriesStrings.upMd).matches) {
    return originalSpacing(...args);
  }
// use the ratio you want. this will return 4 on mobile devices insted of 8 on desktop
  const relativeSpacing = args.map(spacing => spacing / 2);
  return originalSpacing(...relativeSpacing);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the spacing in the theme depending on the string query

```
    import { createTheme, ThemeProvider, useMediaQuery } from '@mui/material'
    import { ReactNode, useMemo } from 'react'
    
    type Props = {
      children?: ReactNode
    }
    export function Provider(props: Props) {
      const isMobile = useMediaQuery('(max-width:600px)')
    
      const theme = useMemo(
        () => createTheme({ spacing: isMobile ? 4 : 8 })),
        [isMobile],
      )
    
      return <ThemeProvider theme={theme} {...props} />
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try react device detect, it allows to determine on what device you are running your code and create specific behaviours depending on it

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-device-detect

Comment: this is not exactly what I need. In theme, we can set the spacing value (i.e 8, 16, ...). What I need is using ```theme.breakpoints``` to control this spacing value.